# How to get an elements of given class that generated by javascripts

Tags: import

I want to get the **number** of total pages of a given search resluts of this site: http://srh.bankofchina.com/search/whpj/searchen.jsp, e.g., from 2015-1-12 to 2015-1-13 the currency of USD by the following code:

```
$initialUrl = "http://srh.bankofchina.com/search/whpj/searchen.jsp";
startdate = "2015-01-12";
enddate = DateString[{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}];
name = "1336"; (*only USD*)

$parameters = {"erectDate" -> startdate, "nothing" -> enddate, 
   "pjname" -> name};
$results = Import[$initialUrl, "Data"
  , "RequestMethod" -> "POST"
  , "RequestParameters" -> $parameters]
$results // ColumnForm;
```

But it seems that the **Data** did not include the **total number** of pages (as in the following graph).

[image: total number]

So is there still a way to get the total number of pages, such that I can get all the results page by page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem exactly as it is stated - by finding the element with class "nav_pagenum" - I suggest [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71915/731) solution. On that page there are also links to posts where it is shown how to retrieve the element using `Cases`. Below I present a toy solution that I just happened upon.

---

When you request a page that does not exist it will simply return the last page that does exist. The major drawback of this approach is that you cannot get the page asynchronously.

```
requestData[startdate_, enddate_, currency_][page_] := Module[
  {url = "http://srh.bankofchina.com/search/whpj/searchen.jsp", parameters},
  parameters = {"erectDate" -> startdate, "nothing" -> enddate, "pjname" -> currency, "page" -> ToString@page};
  Rest[Import[url, "Data", "RequestMethod" -> "POST", "RequestParameters" -> parameters]][[1, 2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
  ]

startdate = "2015-01-12";
enddate = DateString[{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}];
name = "1336";(*only USD*)

p = 0;
data = {};
last = requestData[startdate, enddate, name][1];
new = requestData[startdate, enddate, name][2];
While[new =!= last,
  last = new;
  new = requestData[startdate, enddate, name][p];
  AppendTo[data, new];
  p++;
  ];
results = Most@data;
```

Comment: what's the logic of the while loop?

Comment: @vanabel It continues until the last retrieved page is the same as the formerly retrieved page. This works because if you request a page that doesn't exist it returns the last page that does.

Comment: I mean if there is only one page, then no data will output?

Comment: @vanabel I can help you fix that special case, if you need it. I only attempted to show a way to do this, I think that now that you know this trick you may be able to write code for that special case yourself.

Comment: thanks, please help me again, the logic is not easy to me.

Comment: @vanabel OK, note that `new` and `last` is defined before the loop even starts. If, before the loop even starts, `new == last` then there is only one page. So `If[new == last, new, While...]`.

Comment: Why the last Most is needed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally get the following:
data = {};
last = requestData[startdate, enddate, name][1];
p = 1;
While[data = data~Join~last; p++; 
 new = requestData[startdate, enddate, name][p]; last =!= new,
 last = new;
 ]
data // Length

Comment: @vanabel `Most` is needed because it retrieves one duplicate before it realizes that it is a duplicate. Please, I don't think you should accept this. Not yet at least. It didn't find the number by parsing the HTML as you requested. It was just a solution I happened upon, and thought I should post.

Comment: yes, this is not a directly solution, but it works for me, so I think is ok. Also the original question is still interesting.

Comment: @vanabel Updated with a small note that may be of interest.